# Cómo obtener suma por agrupaciones en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo una tabla en SQL que tiene datos como se muestra de la siguiente manera:

| Policy | Amount | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9749982 | 87.79 | 11/1/2021 |
| 9749982 | 87.79 | 7/1/2021 |
| 9749988 | 67.94 | 11/1/2020 |
| 9749988 | 135.88 | 11/1/2020 |
| 9749988 | 67.94 | 1/1/2021 |
| 9749991 | 154.52 | 1/1/2021 |
| 9749991 | 154.52 | 4/1/2022 |
| 9749991 | 154.52 | 5/1/2022 |

De qué manera puedo hacer un query que me muestre los resultados de la suma de los amounts por cada policy, es decir, que quede de la siguiente manera:

| Policy | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 9749982 | 87.79 |
| 9749982 | 87.79 |
| 9749988 | 67.94 |

Comment: pero si tu salida esperada es igual a la salida que ya tienes? no solo sería quitar del select la columna effectivedate?

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes probar de la siguiente menara:

```
SELECT Policy, sum(Amount)
    FROM [nombre_tabla]
    group by Policy;
```